# NullPointerException with XMLpullparser

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlpullparser

maybe I don't see it. I use the xpppullpullparser.

This code starts the XmlPullparser and reads the xml data from a http stream. (The stream does work, I tested it)

String _text = "";

```
            try {
                // Startet den XML Leser
                XmlPullParserFactory factory =    XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
                try {
                    // Startet die Connection, um XML Daten zu bekommen
                    URL _url = new URL(url[0]);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) _url.openConnection();
                    _text = readStream(con.getInputStream());
                    // Setzt xml auf Input an
                    xpp.setInput(new StringReader(_text));
                    readXML(xpp);
```

Now here is the readXML function. It should parse the XML into weatherData object. (It isn't important what is weatherData because parsing isn't working)

```
private weatherData readXML(XmlPullParser xpp)
{
    weatherData _result = new weatherData();
    try {
        int _eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        String _name;

        while (_eventType != xpp.END_DOCUMENT) {
            _name = xpp.getName();
            if (_name == null)
            Log.i("i", "Tja, null...");
            if (_name.equals("city") && _eventType == xpp.START_TAG)
            {

                int _id = Integer.parseInt(xpp.getAttributeValue("", "id"));
                Log.i("_id", new Integer(_id).toString());

            }
            xpp.next();
            _eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("i", "exception: " + e.getMessage() + " " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

return _result;
}
```

xpp.getName() just gives me an empty string. Any ideas, why?

Comment: Post your logs from logcat

Comment: Can you post the xml?

Comment: Link to the xml is http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Hamburg&mode=xml

log is this

03-08 12:41:41.208  19603-19760/com.test.wetter.wetterapp I/i﹕ Tja, null...
03-08 12:41:41.209  19603-19760/com.test.wetter.wetterapp E/i﹕ exception: null null

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know for sure what's happening here, since you didn't post the XML that's being parsed, or any additional information regarding where specifically this is happening.

However, it is natural for the `XmlPullParser` to return `null` on `getName()` when the `eventType` is equal to `XmlPullParser.TEXT` (indicating that character data was read and will be available by calling `getText()`). In this case, you'll want to call the `getText()` method to get the content of the XML tag.

Comment: hey link to xml is http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Hamburg&mode=xml

Comment: And is it failing on "Germany"?, if so, then this is ur problem. You need to make sure to check what the event type is, and if it's "TEXT", then you need to call "getText()" to assign the inner-value of the "Country" xml tag.

Comment: Hey, i changed it this way: 

                if ( _eventType == xpp.START_TAG && xpp.getName().equals("city"))
                {

                    int _id = Integer.parseInt(xpp.getAttributeValue("", "id"));
                    // Log.i("_id", new Integer(_id).toString());
                    _result.set_id(_id);
                }

Now it will look first if there is a normal tag. Thank you for your tip.